# LVDS screen for embedded Linux

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to add a LVDS screen on embedded Linux 3.14.52.

Screen's resolution is 800x480 then he will use LDB-WVGA. But I can't find any "timing structure" for wvga in the device tree. There is structure for XGA, WXGA, fullHD.

Do I need to add a timing structure for wvga? If yes, is this structure have to be specific of my screen?

Best regards,

Comment: Yes, you need to add timing structure for WVGA (specific to your LVDS display) in the device tree. Importantly, need to to use added WVGA timing structure. for ex: display = <wvga_display_timings>;

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
Since my last message, I added a new timing structure in lvds-channel@0 specific to my LVDS screen. 
But I don't know where I have to add "display = <wvga_display_timings>"
I search the part of the code where timing structure is used. Apparently it is in ldb.c. But I'm pretty sure it is not the correct to put this line..

Comment: Need to add it in device tree file only. Any one timing structure would be made as default in order to make display work. In place of the default timing structure use the newly added timing structure. If possible, can you share me your dts or dtsi file?

Comment: Here is the DTSI file : http://www.partage-facile.com/LRXUA16TTC/imx6qdl_apalis_a3mod.dtsi.html

As you will see there is many timing structure for different mode ( xga, wxga...). I added myself wvga.

Comment: https://www.nelson-miller.com/what-is-lvds-in-lcds/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the lvds0 structure as below,

```
lvds-channel@0 {
        reg = <0>;
        fsl,data-mapping = "spwg"; /* "jeida"; */
        fsl,data-width = <18>;
        crtc = "ipu2-di1";
        primary;
        status = "okay";

        display = <&display0_wvga>;

        display0_wvga: display_wvga_800x480 {
            display-timings {
                native-mode = <&timing_wvga>;

                /* Custom WVGA Timing Structure */
                timing_wvga: 800x480 {
                    clock-frequency = <33200000>; // 33.20 MHz
                    hactive = <800>;
                    vactive = <480>;
                    hback-porch = <40>;
                    hfront-porch = <88>;
                    vback-porch = <1>;
                    vfront-porch = <23>;
                    hsync-len = <60>;
                    vsync-len = <10>;
                    hsync-active = <0>;
                    vsync-active = <0>;
                    pixelclk-active = <0>;
                };
            };

        };

        display1_svga: display_svga_800x600 {
            display-timings {
                native-mode = <&timing_svga>;

                /* LDB-AM-800600LTNQW-A0H */
                timing_svga: 800x600 {
                    clock-frequency = <55000000>;
                    hactive = <800>;
                    vactive = <600>;
                    hback-porch = <112>;
                    hfront-porch = <32>;
                    vback-porch = <3>;
                    vfront-porch = <17>;
                    hsync-len = <80>;
                    vsync-len = <4>;
                    hsync-active = <0>;
                    vsync-active = <0>;
                    pixelclk-active = <0>;
                };
            };

        };

        display2_xga: display_xga_1024x768 {
            display-timings {
                native-mode = <&timing_xga>;

                /* Standard XGA timing */
                timing_xga: 1024x768 {
                    clock-frequency = <65000000>;
                    hactive = <1024>;
                    vactive = <768>;
                    hback-porch = <160>;
                    hfront-porch = <24>;
                    vback-porch = <29>;
                    vfront-porch = <3>;
                    hsync-len = <136>;
                    vsync-len = <6>;
                    hsync-active = <0>;
                    vsync-active = <0>;
                    pixelclk-active = <0>;
                };
            };

        };

        display3_wxga: display_wxga_1200x800 {
            display-timings {
                native-mode = <&timing_wxga>;

                timing_wxga: 1200x800 {
                    clock-frequency = <68930000>;
                    hactive = <1280>;
                    vactive = <800>;
                    hback-porch = <64>;
                    hfront-porch = <64>;
                    vback-porch = <5>;
                    vfront-porch = <5>;
                    hsync-len = <40>;
                    vsync-len = <6>;
                    hsync-active = <0>;
                    vsync-active = <0>;
                    pixelclk-active = <0>;
                };
            };

        };

        display4_fullhd: display_fullhd_1920x1080 {
            display-timings {
                native-mode = <&timing_fullhd>;

                timing_fullhd: 1920x1080 {
                    clock-frequency = <138500000>;
                    hactive = <1920>;
                    vactive = <1080>;
                    hback-porch = <80>;
                    hfront-porch = <48>;
                    vback-porch = <23>;
                    vfront-porch = <3>;
                    hsync-len = <32>;
                    vsync-len = <5>;
                    hsync-active = <0>;
                    vsync-active = <0>;
                    pixelclk-active = <0>;
                };
            };
        };
    };
```

As per my knowledge, it should work. Check and feedback.

Comment: I compiled the new kernel with the .dtsi file. The screen isn't detect (I think), when I type the command line fb-test, the screen remain black

Comment: I think so, before the update I could see some purple lines on the screen (due of a missconfiguration I think). That's why I thought the LVDS configuration (wvga) wasn't use by linux

Comment: Once again check the timing structure data and also check if LVDS device is been probed or not i.e. detected or not during boot up?

Comment: Maybe ldb driver is not able to properly retrieve the device tree structure data I guess :( due to this update. Switch to previous or modify ldb driver

Comment: The timing structure might be correct because I'm using the same data with the same screen on another kernel. During boot the screen display some purple line. But when I type "fb-test", the screen display more random line.

Comment: May I know, which kernel version is been used and let me know if it's customized kernel or mainline (open source)? Just to go through ldb driver.

Comment: Kernel 3.14.52, I didn't customise ldb or any screen driver

Comment: I wonder if I forget to add an option about LVDS in Buildroot

Comment: I don't have time anymore to work on this project ^^ I'll work back on this project later! Thanks for your help anyway :)